# Django Can't Find My Templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm running Python 2.6.1 and Django 1.2.1 on Windows XP SP3.  I'm using JetBrains PyCharm 1.0 to create and deploy my Django apps.

I'm relatively inexperienced with Python, and I'm starting to learn Django by following along with "Writing Your First Django App" from the web site - the poll application.  I'm stuck on [part 3](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/).

Everything is fine when I add the simple callback functions for "Writing your first view".

I hit the snag when I get to "Write views that actually do something."

I followed the instructions to modify the index view:

1. Add a new method to views.py (Note - template is ready from 'polls/index.html'):
2. Add index.html template to `site-templates/polls/` folder
3. Modify settings.py to point to `site-templates` folder

Here's the code in my views.py:

```
from django.template import Context, loader
from polls.models import Poll
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    latest_poll_list = Poll.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    t = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
    c = Context({
        'latest_poll_list': latest_poll_list,
    })
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

Here's the line in my settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = ('/site-templates/')
```

But still I get this message when I run:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /polls/
polls/index.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/polls/
Django Version: 1.2.1
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
polls/index.html
```

The exception is thrown in loader.py.  My debug settings look like this:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS 
('django.core.context_processors.auth', 'django.core.context_processors.request')
TEMPLATE_DEBUG  
True
TEMPLATE_DIRS   
('/site-templates',)
TEMPLATE_LOADERS    
('django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader', 'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader')
```

My directory structure looks like this:

[image]

What did I miss?  Is the settings.py incorrect?  Please advise.

Comment: You specify the contents of `TEMPLATE_DIRS` twice (the 2nd is correct, the 1st not). Which one are you really using?

Comment: Can you post your folder hierarchy?

Comment: The first entry is from my settings.py; the second is what is echoed back into the browser when I invoke the URL.

Comment: What happens when you put the value from the debug traceback into settings.py, replacing the one you have already?

Comment: Now my app and the admin URLs are having an issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You must use absolute paths in the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting.

Convenient thing to do, at the top of your settings, insert:

```
import os
DIRNAME = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Then anywhere you use a path, use `os.path.join`.
Example, your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` would become:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(DIRNAME, 'site-templates/'),
)
```

Comment: Sorry, ive never used django or even python for that matter on windows. There must quirk about paths that i am unaware of

Comment: I've seen this on both linux and windows.  What he's complaining about is that Template_dirs doesn't traverse properly as a list.  You should theoretically be able to specify app specific template dirs by doing a recursive listing and searching for template folders.  Then append them to the list.  Multiple entry Template_dirs lists either a) don't parse intuitively or b) fail to parse at all.  I suspect the latter since debug output only gives me one file open failure/file does not exist error and it's the first entry.

Answer (score 42):

I was faced to the same problem. The mistake in my case was, that the 'app' was not in the `INSTALLED_APPS` list at the project settings.py file.

The error raise an error message they suggests similar error.

```
line 25, in get_template TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: authControll/index.html
```

**settings.py --> Application definition**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'authControll'
]
```

Comment: If you are just starting out with django, THIS is probably going to solve your problem.

Comment: I forgot to add the apps in installed apps. I didn't understand why the templates in the apps couldn't get found, but the projects folder templates was found.

Answer (score 6):

Django has a sort of patterns and philosophy. Try to use the same configurations other wise you have to change the core patterns in django.

The pattern for templates in django are like this:

```
polls/templates/polls/index.html
```

But to use it you have to add the installed app at the configs:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'polls.apps.PollsConfig', #<-- Here this shoud be solve it
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',]
```

For more information look at:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial02/#activating-models

Comment: Would `'polls',` work the same as `'polls.apps.PollsConfig',`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51067778/django-installed-apps-polls-vs-polls-apps-pollsconfig

Comment: In this case I realy do not know, but It should be preferable to use the full path as the PEP says. https://peps.python.org/pep-0366/

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was simply bad positioning:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'histories',
]
```

My solution was :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'histories',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will surely solve the issue, instead of all the above try adding only below line in `settings.py` :

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    "appname/templates",
)
```

Comment: Can you please explain why you think this will *surely solve the issue*?

Comment: This doesn't make sense as OP's templates don't even live inside app folders and this is apparent from the post.

Answer (score -6):

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/api/#loading-templates
Small fix for @zsquare answer:

```
import os
DIRNAME = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

TEMPLATE_DIRS = ( DIRNAME+'/site-templates/' )
```

Comment: This is just bad, it does not *fix* anything, instead it breaks the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` by not having a tuple there.