# Django INSTALLED_APPS 'polls' vs 'polls.apps.PollsConfig'

Tags: django

In every youtube tutorial I'v seen people simply add "app_name" to INSTALLED_APPS list.
Yesterday I started Official Django Tutorial and they suggest "app_name.apps.App_nameConf" notations. 
Im guessing official way is a better way and it's not hard to memorize additional syntax, I just wanna be sure. Because stuff works ether way.
Please give me a simple, easy to understand answer so even I could get it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**You are right**, following official way is a proper way, since the created video tutorials or third party blogs may refer to the older version of the django and such way is deprecated now.

Good luck in your beginnings!

Comment: Thanks. Thing is, there are many tutorials no youtube, and I only watch new once plus I read a book on Django. All of those tutorials and book use Django version 1.9 or 1.10 so do I. Now Im going trough Django Official Tutorial version 1.10 as well and only in it I saw "polls.apps.PollsConfig" notation. I guess youtubers just didn't think it's important.

Comment: Likely that was copy paste from previous similar tutorials. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

In `INSTALLED_APPS` one can specify all apps used in this **django project app**.

However, you can create **multiple apps** in one project. By default this would result in separate directories name in root project directory.

As all apps are in root project directory - this allows to specify only (their) directory name in INSTALLED_APPS.

On the other hand, **we can specify full path to project sub-app AppConfig**, not relying on auto-discovering / that sub-app is located in root project directory etc.

---

**Multiple apps in one project?**

Yes, multiple apps of one project are usually tightly coupled to this specific project and cannot be used outside of it.

The main idea is [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) - to split the logic into separate sections, each responsible for some part of project app.

When your app starts growing, more different logic is being added to it,  `models.py` / `views.py` / `forms.py` etc starts growing, **making it difficult to read and understand project structure as a whole**.

Even in small project - **separating into sub-apps may be very helpful in terms of organizing things**.

There are different styles of how to organize your django app, like where should sub-apps directories be located (i.e. in root directory, or in sub-directory with project name), and apps and settings directories can be located not in root project directory.  In such cases being able to specify path directly to `AppConfig class` is nice and also more **explicit**, which **is better than implicit**.

---

`default_app_config` is mostly used in reusable apps - apps intended to be distributed and used by other people - published to [pypi](https://pypi.org/). This allows just add their name in `INSTALLED_APPS`, not full path to their AppConfig.

You should not use it in your project unless you know that you need it.

Comment: So I'm supposed to add `'app1.apps.App1Config',` instead of `'app1',`.

Comment: For your project's app (`app1` directory with app in your django project) direct form `app1` in INSTALLED_APPS can be used. However, imho, it is preferred to create even simple AppConfig  file (with just app name) for your apps and use 'app1.apps.App1Config' form. Keeping short form like `app1` only for externally installed packages, for which `import_module("app1")` is used internally. That way it is more clear which packages are local / project ones, which are external; ready to extend later AppConfig file without changing installed_apps list.

Answer (score 0):

The `polls.apps.PollsConfig` is the newer, more explicit way, and it better allows multiple configurations of the same app.

The reason why `polls` works is that `polls/__init__.py` likely has a

```
default_app_config = 'polls.apps.PollsConfig'
```

line.

Comment: My polls/__init__.py has nothing in it at all :)

Comment: The `polls/__init__.py` created by `startapp` is deliberately empty. If `default_app_config` is not specified, Django uses the base `AppConfig` class. The [docs discourage setting `default_app_config`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/applications/#configuring-applications), it's meant for apps that predate Django 1.7.

Comment: This was changed after the Django version 1.9.  Until 1.8, Django Documentation advised just to add 'polls'. You can check it by changing the Django Documentation version at the bottom.  But it wasn't state the reason to that change.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/applications/#for-application-users

Comment: **Django 1.10**: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial02/#activating-models **Django 1.8**: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/#activating-models

Answer (score 0):

You have to activate your model, and Django needs to know that you have your app installed.
So in settings.py you need to add 'polls.apps.PollsConfig' in INSTALLED_APPS topic because in your app.py file you have likely defined a class PollsConfig:

In settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  'polls.apps.PollsConfig,
  'django.contrib.admin',
  '<other app...>',
]
```

In apps.py

```
class PollsConfig(AppConfig)
    name = 'polls'
```