# Why can't you find the template?

Tags: python, django

This is settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

This is my views.py

```py
def iniciar_sesion(request):
    return render(request,'registrar/iniciar_sesion.html')
```

This is the structure

```
appweb
|-plantillas
   |-registrar
     |-iniciar_sesion.html
```

It's strange that he can't find it, I don't know why he doesn't

[image: Structure with image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Can't Find My Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065045/django-cant-find-my-templates)

Comment: @AminSamani nope, please see now the questions becuase i edit

Comment: Have you tried renaming `plantillas` to `templates`?

Comment: @Jacinator see te photo

Comment: `APPS_DIRS=true` [means](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#templates) that django will look into `templates/` folder under each app. This is not what your folder structure looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Your settings for the template dirs is os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"templates"), but your folder structure shows plantillas/registrar/iniciar_session.html.

change the templates to plantillas in the DIRS:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"plantillas")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

In the future, when Django cannot find your templates, use the Template-loader postmortem which is the first gray section under the yellow bar saying TemplateDoesNotExist at /.  It will tell you where it is trying to look and you can compare it to where it should be looking.

Hope this helps!

Comment: in the views.py how to call?, call like render(request,'registrar/iniciar_sesion.html')

Comment: Yes, does this not work for you?

Comment: nope, you have discord?..

Comment: Sure, what is your username or server link?